# Finding the plane where the line lies on

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Having a line and a normal orthogonal to it, how do I find the plane in which the normal will come out from and the line will lie on?

Comment: $\mathbf{n}\cdot(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a})=0$ is normal plane equation where $\mathbf{n}$ is the normal, $\mathbf{x}=(x,y,z)^T$ and $\mathbf{a}$ is a point on the plane (you can take any point on the line for $\mathbf{a}$)

Comment: So,let $l$ be a line with a vector $u$ perpendicular to the line, you have to find a plane $\pi$ such that its orthogonal vector is $u$ and $l \subset \pi$, right?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdinwhat would `T` be? @psidaga exactly.

Comment: $T$ means transpose:  $(x,y,z)^T=\pmatrix {x\\y\\z}$

Comment: Ok, perfect. Are you in 3-dimensional space or in a general n-dimensional affine space?

Comment: I'm in 3d space. Worse than that, I'm writing programming code. Haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the three-dimensional affine space $\mathbb{A^3}_{\mathbb{R}}$ (I'm assuming $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$) a line is defined, in its cartesian form, by the intersection of two planes.

Let $l$:\begin{cases} ax+by+cz+d=0 \\ a'x+b'y+c'z+d'=0 \end{cases} and $\textbf{u}$ a vector orthogonal to the line.

We can consider the pencil of planes with support the line $l$ such that $$\Lambda_{\mu,\eta}: \mu (ax+by+cz+d) + \eta(a'x+b'y+c'z+d')=0$$
that can be written as $x(\mu a + \eta a')+y(\mu b + \eta b')+z(\mu c + \eta c')+\mu d+\eta d'=0$, where $$\textbf{v}=(\mu a + \eta a', \mu b + \eta b',\mu c + \eta c')$$ is the parametrization of its orthogonal vector.

So, in order to find the plane we only have to solve the system $\textbf{v}= \rho \textbf{u}$ (the two vectors have to be proportional).

Comment: That solves my problem. But I was looking into the documentation of my programming language/library and found out that a plane can be generated by using 3 points that are on it as long as they are not forming a line. Probably very dummy question: is it possible to get multiple perpendiculars of the unit normal by just swapping x, y and z in different combinations?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the terms d and d' (they were not really important for our problem). Now it's correct at all I think.

Comment: I'm not understanding if you are looking for the equation of the plane for those three points or for another thing...

Comment: Never mind. I got the problem solved with your main answer already. Thanks.

Comment: What is $\rho$ ?

Comment: With $\rho$ I mean that the two vectors have to be proportional. For example, $\textbf{v}$ is a multiple of $\textbf{u}$.

Comment: I suspect the asker's line is defined by a point and a direction vector, but that is his/her problem.